# Batch edit gridview devexpress

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview, batch-processing

Working with DevExpress GridView binded from database in batch edit mode, i have different radio buttons ( that i want to switch on/off ) and keeping only one selected. The issues I ran into are :

- I can't seem to get how only one to be active
- Using [DataItemTemplate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Da890.png) with ASPxRadioButton, when clicking on it, it turn into edit mode and show True/False, in this case when editing it fire batch update event :

  ```
   <devex:GridViewDataTextColumn VisibleIndex="4" FieldName="GC_TypePrudent" Caption="Prudent" CellStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"><DataItemTemplate><devex:ASPxRadioButton ID="PrudentRadioBox"  runat="server" CssPostfix="BlackGlass Checked="<%# Eval("GC_TypePrudent") == DBNull.Value ? false :  Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("GC_TypePrudent")) %>" Enabled="true" /></DataItemTemplate></devex:GridViewDataTextColumn>
  ```
- Using [EditItemTemplate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkAKH.png) with ASPxRadioButton, it shows True/False and when clicking on it and perform to save changes with external button, it doesn't fire batch update event although I made update edit of the gridview:

  ```
  <devex:GridViewDataTextColumn VisibleIndex="5" FieldName="GC_TypeEquilibre" Caption="Equilibré" CellStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"><EditItemTemplate><devex:ASPxRadioButton ID="EquilibreRadioBox"  runat="server" CssPostfix="BlackGlass Checked="<%# Eval("GC_TypeEquilibre") == DBNull.Value ? false :  Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("GC_TypeEquilibre")) %>" Enabled="true" /></EditItemTemplate></devex:GridViewDataTextColumn>
  ```